# VMware + Windows Server 2012 R2 : Cannot View Website outside of VM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-workstation, iis-8

This incident occurred several days ago and has shown to be quite a nightmare. Essentially, as I attempt to access some web pages from outside of my VM, *ERR_CONNECTION_RESET* errors are thrown.

As I attempt to access these webpages from within my VM, I am greeted by the *Windows Server : Internet Information Services* page instead of the home page of my local website.

After doing some research on the subject I noticed that this could be a problem regarding TCP-IP / DNS or with the binding settings. But after flushing and restoring the IP, resetting the DNS, and double checking my Bindings / Domain, I had no luck.

Any Ideas?

Comment: On the vswitch configured for that VM, any other VM on it ? Does they have same symptom ? I suspect a vswitch error versus a physical switch error.

Comment: There are no other VMs on my machine